# Chaining formula parts in Excel

Tags: excel, xml, xpath

I want to chain in one Excel formula `webservice` and `filterxml`, but fail on something... The goal is to read out certain information with XPath from an API answer page, which is XML.

I'm doing so:

`=DUMP(FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE(https://example.com/api);"response/answer/result";"position"))`

But i get in this no meaningful error and don't know, what to adjust :( I'm using Office 365, so `filterxml` and `webservice` should work, as far i know.

**UP**:

After adding quotes to url, like `=DUMP(FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE("https://example.com/api");"response/answer/result";"position"))` got a further error `too much arguments`.

Shortening the XPath to `=DUMP(FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE("https://example.com/api");"response/answer/result/@position"))` did the work successfully.

Comment: The url needs to be quoted as a string literal.

Comment: @Jeeped thank you, your recommendation and some buggering about did the work

Comment: I rolled back your edit. It is not proper to add the word SOLVED to your title. If you found a solution and you'd like to share it, write an answer in the space below to do so. It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question here - see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for information on how to do so properly.